# Joda Time String to Date and time convertion

Tags: android, datetime, jodatime, datetimepicker

I have a date format -

> 01-12-2015

I need to convert it to using jodatime

> 2015-12-01T18:47:37.8688573Z

what I did -

```
public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
    StartDate = DateTime.parse(startDate);
}
```

Getting error -

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "30-11-2015" is malformed at "15"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

joda-time does not support microseconds.

You can parse it as in below:

```
String date = "01-12-2015";
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"));

System.out.println(dateTime);
//2015-12-01T00:00:00.000+02:00
```